# Cannot Delete Default User, Password, and Vhost - RabbitMQ Dockerfile

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, dockerfile

I'm trying to write a `Dockerfile` that copies a custom `conf` and sets the default user, password, and vhost to something other than `/` `guest` `guest`.  I tried with environmental variables first but when I logged into the management UI, all the default stuff is still there!

I then tried issuing the `CMD` and it still doesn't work:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.8.2-management

#ENV RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=test
#ENV RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=test
#ENV RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=test

COPY rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

CMD ["sh", "-c", "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_auth_backend_http; rabbitmq-server", "rabbitmqctl add_user test test", "rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test administrator", "rabbitmqctl delete_user guest", "rabbitmqctl delete_vhost /", "rabbitmqctl add_vhost testvhost", "rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p test testvhost \".*\" \".*\" \".*\""]
```

I found if I bash into the container after its spun up and run `rabbitmqctl add_user test test` it does add the new user.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though because I am overriding the `conf` with my own configuration in `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf` the `ENV` vars don't seem to be having an effect on the default `user`, `password`, and `vhost`.

My solution was to put them in my configuration:

```
loopback_users.guest = false
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
management.listener.port = 15672
default_user = test
default_pass = test
default_vhost = test
```

I hope this helps anyone else in this situation.